# Is this question wrong? possible to calculate gain without beta or Ic given?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, analog, bjt, semiconductors

How to proceed with this question? I can't think from where to start.[image: This is only question, no values were given. "[4]" represents marks of the question.]

Comment: I can make it have a gain of >100, but I think if you make reasonable assumptions and start with the operating point you'll come to a different conclusion.

Comment: I believe that posting question (a) too would help a lot. What shown so far seems nonsense

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany. Max gain 96 at 25 C :-)

Comment: @carloc Question (a) is not related to this.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Okay, I'll bite.

Comment: Gain for fully bypassed or grounded emitter is 38.4 x voltage across collector resistor. This reaches a maximum as Vrc reaches Vcc. // Re = 26 Ohms per mA. Vc= RC X mA. Leading to the gain of 38.4 per volt of Vc. ((On phone - better answer can be given if desired))

Answer (score 1):

What "could be" the max collector current? Ic = 2.5V /50k = **50 uA**

**What is Vbe if Ic = 1mA ?   (Answer  ~ = 600mV)**

- **you should try to remember this and confirm on your own in any datasheets.**

**What is this Vbe?  800 mV**

So the collector is not longer an ideal (infinite impedance) current sink **and is now a saturated switch.**

Whenever an analog output is saturated, you no longer have any gain.  ( you might see an attenuated asymmetric wiggle here with some 100mVpp input on 800mV)

So what is the voltage gain here? **"none"**

**What is the current gain? (none)**

there's actually a loss here if Vbe = 800 mV drives maybe 100mA to > 1A while Ic = 50 uA  in making a switch and you need to put in 10x base current to achieve "rated" Vce(Sat)

So you would never use this circuit as shown.

Comment: Just for fun: long long long ago I needed a high side switch for a voltage sense resistor divider. I wanted very low switch voltage drop. Now a low Rdson FET would be the obvious choice. Then not so much so. I used a PNP bipolar with. Forced beta close to 1. Current was still small and only present during sampling. Vcesat was far far lower than published typical and constant enough.

Comment: Essentially a current mirror comparator